# Using label in plt.plot gives one legend instead of two different legends

Tags: matplotlib

[Image having the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D67fR.png)this is showing label in same line and only for one object.

```
label=["Training Data","Linear Regression"]
plt.plot(X[:,1],X.dot(theta),label=label)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is expected. If you need each line to have its own label, you need to plot them separately, or create a custom legend. The latter might look as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = np.random.randn(20,2)
theta = np.random.rand(2,2)

label=["Training Data","Linear Regression"]

lines = plt.plot(X[:,1], X.dot(theta))
plt.legend(lines, label)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: .. in that case your data contains only one line. If that is the case, passing a list as labels may not make too much sense anyways.